# creating flume agent in hortonworks sandbox vm for streaming weather data into HDFS

Tags: hdfs, flume, data-stream

I am configuring flume to stream weather data,
i have written flume agent as given below,

WeatherAgent.sources= Weather

WeatherAgent.sinks = hdfs-write

WeatherAgent.channels= memory-channel

WeatherAgent.sources.Weather.type = weather

WeatherAgent.sources.Weather.bind = api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=*********

WeatherAgent.sources.Weather.port = 11111

WeatherAgent.sinks.hdfs-write.type = hdfs

WeatherAgent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hadoop/flume

WeatherAgent.sinks.hdfs-write.rollInterval = 30

WeatherAgent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

WeatherAgent.sinks.hdfs-write.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

WeatherAgent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory

WeatherAgent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity=10000

WeatherAgent.sources.Weather.channels=memoryChannel

WeatherAgent.sinks.hdfs-write.channel=memoryChannel

i am getting error as

> weather agent does not contain any valid channels making it as invalid.

i am new to flume,i dont know which all parameters to be addded in agent config file,i even dont know written agent is correct or wrong,please help me to solve this.
if any Help links are there to write custom or new agents please post.

thanks in advance

Suyog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 it is type mismatching. In your configuration file you mentioned  

    WeatherAgent.channels= memory-channel

  but you are using  memoryChannel instead of memory-channel

    WeatherAgent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory

    WeatherAgent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity=10000

    WeatherAgent.sources.Weather.channels=memoryChannel
```

Comment: thank you sravan for your help .. channel issue is resolve but i am not able to get data its giving warning as no configuration found for this host.

Comment: thank you sravan for your help .. channel issue is resolve but i am not able to get data its giving warning as no configuration found for this host.it is stopping by saying starting new configuration,please help me on this

Comment: hi sravan with your help i am able to solve above errors now i am getting one more error "UNABLE TO START EVENTDRIVENSOURCE RUNNER " please help me on this

Comment: can you post detailed error log

Comment: hi sorry to ask this but can please tell me where can i find error log of flume becoz log4j properties file does not any information realated to this agent.  and please tell me where can put all text of error coz here comment opton has charector limit i cant copy entire exception here. please help i am new on this.

Comment: Hi sravan i can copy only this much in comment please help on this ERROR lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Unable to start EventDriv
enSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.NetcatSource{name:Weather,state
:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
        at org.apache.flume.source.NetcatSource.start(NetcatSource.java:168)
        at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSour
ceRunner.java:44)